# How to Install Json Api Plugin in worldpress website

Tags: wordpress

I am not wordpress developer Basically I have android application template for wordpress website. My client send me a Json Api to upload that file to "**/wp-content/plugins/**".I am android developer having no exp with server side. so can any one guide what I have to do(I mean what I have to do to access this path).

Comment: https://codex.wordpress.org/Managing_Plugins#Manual_Plugin_Installation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**JSON API WP**

**You just call recent api plugin like - ...../json=get_recent_posts**

```
*response for the get_recent_post* 
{
  "status": "ok",
  "count": 10,
  "count_total": 79,
  "pages": 7,
  "posts": [
    { ... },
    { ... },
    ...
  ]
}
```

Explicit mode examples:

http://www.example.org/?json=get_recent_posts

http://www.example.org/?json=get_post&post_id=47

http://www.example.org/?json=get_tag_posts&tag_slug=banana

With user-friendly permalinks configured:

http://www.example.org/api/get_recent_posts/

http://www.example.org/api/get_post/?post_id=47

http://www.example.org/api/get_tag_posts/?tag_slug=banana

**for details follow this link**

https://wordpress.org/plugins/json-api/other_notes/

**Rather then json api try new wp rest api 2 which is feature of wp-4.4**

http://v2.wp-api.org/

1. downlaod plugin and install it.
2. just type /wp-json/wp/v2/posts in end of your site url and you will get all post.

for get all post

```
www.mysite.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts
```

For the search functionality - search test post

```
/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?filter[s]=test
```

much more details from this link 
http://v2.wp-api.org/reference/posts/

Note for best result use latest version of WP